# Is a function space necessarily a vector space?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, definition

I have a very basic question.

> In a function space, do we require the set of functions to form a vector space$?$ Or it can be any arbitrary set of functions$?$

I tried to search a bit but could not find a satisfactory answer. It'd be great if one can provide me a *complete* definition of function space. Thank you.

Comment: How are you defining a "function space"?  I'd have said it was a fairly loose concept which would include, say, the set of functions between one set and another.  See, for example, the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space)

Comment: Just to stress:  if $X,Y$ are, say, finite sets, then the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$ do not form a vector space.

Comment: Here is Tao's definition of function space. But it is not clear whether it has to be vector space.
https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/function_spaces1.pdf

Comment: In order for a set of functions with common domain and codomain to be a vector space in a natural way, you would need a vector space structure on the codomain. That being said, you can probably make _any_ set into _some_ vector space by just imposing an addition table and scalar multiplication table on it.

Comment: Here is a few examples of function space. But the writer was careful not to give a precise definition of the term.
http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~dstewart/classes/22m176/dfs-notes/node2.html

Comment: @Arthur so when we talk about a normed function space, do we mean a normed vector space, where the vectors are functions$?$

Comment: The concept of a norm does not make sense unless it's in the context of a vector space. I believe "normed space" refers specifically to a vector space with a norm, the same should be true for a normed function space.

Comment: Tao's definition is not standard, and I'd still say it was informal.  He doesn't define "norm" unless one wants to call "which assigns a non-negative number $||f||_X$ to every function $f \in X$" a definition.  Sure, he's thinking about norms in a vector space context but at the start no particular structure on $X$ is assumed.

Comment: @lulu I'm looking for a standard definition of function space. Does there exist one$?$ Or do we only care about normed function spaces, and in general, topological function spaces in mathematics$?$

Comment: As I say, I do not believe there is a standard definition.  I'd say it was fair to say that in context people usually mean vector spaces (and usually have some sort of analytic norm in mind) but I do not believe that there is an agreed upon definition in full.

Answer (score 2):

Tao's definition of a function space:

> A *function space* is a class $X$ of functions (with fixed domain and
>   range), **together with a norm** which assigns a non-negative number $\|f\|_X$
>   to every function $f$ in $X$.

Notably, norms [can only be defined over a vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)).  So long as we suppose that our function space has a norm, we *must* confine our consideration to function spaces that are also vector spaces.  Notably, any function space whose common codomain is a vector space inherits a natural vector space structure.  In particular, we define $\alpha f + g$ via $[\alpha f + g](x) = \alpha f(x) + g(x)$.

As Tao mentions in the footnote, we may more generally consider topological function spaces.  Since this information is given in a footnote, we can presume that topological function spaces (in particular, function spaces that are not necessarily vector spaces) is beyond the scope of those notes.

In most contexts, we can presume that we are only considering these normed function spaces unless the author indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

The only function space I ever encoutered are either normed spaces or topological vector spaces (and hence real or complex vector space). So, I'd say, **yes, function spaces are vector spaces in most occasions**.

Some references are the [notes by Tao](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/function_spaces1.pdf) that has been mentioned in the comments or the [book on function spaces by Triebel](https://books.google.de/books?id=fMUMl6iLMGwC&lpg=PP1&dq=function%20spaces&hl=de&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q=function%20spaces&f=false).